# Getting the node in the same position in the following sibling

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using the HTML agility pack to parse some HTML, of which a fragment is of the form:

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td><a href="remotelink1"><img /></a></td><td></td>
  <td><a href="site2"><img /></a></td><td></td>
  <td><a href="link3"><img /></a></td><td></td>
  <td><a href="site4"><img /></a></td><td></td>
  <td><a href="link5"><img /></a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="text-align: left;" width="200" height="45">a<br>b<br>c</td><td width="17"></td>
  <td style="text-align: left;" width="200">d<br>e<br>f</td><td width="57"></td>
  <td style="text-align: left;" width="200">g<br>h<br>i</td><td width="57"></td>
  <td width="200">j<br>k<br>l</td><td width="57"></td>
  <td width="200">m<br>n<br>o</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><a href="link6"><img /></a></td><td></td>
  <td><a href="site7"><img /></a></td><td></td>
  <td><a href="remotelink8"><img /></a></td><td></td>
  <td><a href="site9"><img /></a></td><td></td>
  <td><a href="link10"><img /></a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="text-align: left;" width="200" height="45">p<br>q<br>r</td><td width="17"></td>
  <td style="text-align: left;" width="200">s<br>t<br>u</td><td width="57"></td>
  <td style="text-align: left;" width="200">v<br>w<br>x</td><td width="57"></td>
  <td width="200">y<br>z<br>aa</td><td width="57"></td>
  <td width="200">ab<br>ac<br>ad</td>
 </tr>
```

The challenge I'm facing is associating each cell with the row "below" it (i.e. at the same position in the following sibling from the parent node). i.e. I want to associate link "remotelink1" with nodes `a<br>b<br>c` and "site2" with `d<br>e<br>f`, etc.

I can get just the cells containing the links no problem with:

```
foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='entry-content']/table/tbody/tr/td[a[@href]]"))
```

But I'm struggling to get the cell underneath, the closest I can get is:

```
var detail = item.SelectSingleNode("../following-sibling::tr/td[position()]");
```

But that gets the position of the node being iterated, not the `item` node in its parent. Can I use an XPath expression to pass the position of the source node into the predicate, to find the cell underneath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with these ugly propositions:

```
//tr[td[a[@href="remotelink1"]]]
 /following-sibling::tr[1]
     /td[ position() = count(//tr/td[a[@href="remotelink1"]]
                                 /preceding-sibling::td) + 1]
```

and

```
//tr[td[a[@href="site2"]]]
 /following-sibling::tr[1]
     /td[ position() = count(//tr/td[a[@href="site2"]]
                                 /preceding-sibling::td) + 1]
```

- targetting the `tr` with the `td` containing the link you want,
- selecting its' following sibling `tr` elements,
- restricting to the first next sibling
- looking for child `td` element
- and filter on those which position is equal to the number of preceding sibling `td`s of the `td` with the link you want, +1 since XPath positions start at 0

I don't know if HTML agility pack supports XPath variables, but you could just change the variable to "remotelink1" then "site2" and use the variable in the 2 `[@href=...]`

Comment: Cunning plan, I adapted the principle to do: `var detail = item.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("../../following-sibling::tr/td[position() = (count(../preceding-sibling::tr/td[a[@href='{0}']]/preceding-sibling::td) + 1)]", item.Attributes["href"].Value));`

Comment: Wicked! Oh, that is fun

Comment: can we use self to simplify the xpath?